# Update all fields in sql table which doesnt have a specific value

Tags: sql, mysql

Im a novice programmer doing my own firsts project and im in need of assistance.

I have two mysql fields:

1. **Product_published** = Y or N
2. **Product_day** = date("z") which is the day of the year 0-365

I'd like to update all "**Product_published**" fields in a table in my sql database.

They are all set to "**Y**" and I would like to update them to "**N**" if the "**Product_day**" field contains a number which is less than the current day.

So if i have 5 products with todays day(350) and 5 with 349 I would like to unpublish the 349 ones by changing "**Y**" to "**N**" in "**Product_publish**".

Best Regards
Ivar Rafn

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET product_published = 'N'
 WHERE product_day < 350
```

Answer (score 2):

This SQL query should fulfill your wish.

```
 UPDATE your_table
 SET Product_published = 'N'
 WHERE Product_day < 350
```